# How do I think of this sequence generator in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I need to generate a sequence like this:
`[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 31, 37, 43, 49, 57, 65, 73, 81]`

(17 numbers in this example)

The algorithm is:
 `[1, (previous + 2), (previous + 2), (previous + 2), (previous + 2), (previous + 4), (previous + 4), (previous + 4), (previous + 4) ...`

So it's +2 for 4 first items, then +4 for next 4, then +6 for next 4. Increment is increased by 2 each four items.

I was able to do a quick and hacky version in Ruby:

```
def sequence
  incr = 0
  (0..16).each.inject([]) do |acc, counter|
    acc << (acc.last || 1) + incr
    incr += 2 if counter.modulo(4) == 0
    acc
  end
end
```

But I am having problems doing the same in Elixir - it turns out super-lame. Like this:

```
def sequence do
  { sequence, _ } =
    0..16
    |> Enum.reduce({[], 0}, fn(counter, {result, incr}) ->
      last = List.last(result)
      if last do
        result = result ++ [last + incr]
      else
        result = [1]
      end
      if rem(counter, 4) == 0 do
        incr = incr + 2
      end
      {result, incr}
    end)
  sequence
end
```

Obviously I should not be thinking imperatively here, but for this problem I can't :D
I am also sure there is an approach where pipes are much more atomic.

How can this problem be solved in an Elixir way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd start the accumulator with `{[1], 0}` to remove the special case you have in the body of the function. `List.last` and `++` are generally not recommended because they are inefficient (`O(n)`). The idiomatic way in Elixir is to build the list in reverse and reverse the list at the end. This means your `List.last` logic can now be handled by pattern matching the head of the list, which is cheap. You should also be getting a warning for assigning `incr` inside the if. The idiomatic way is to do something like `incr = if ..., do: incr + 2, else: incr`.

Here's how I'd write this:

```
(0..16)
|> Enum.reduce({[1], 0}, fn counter, {[h | _] = result, incr} ->
  incr = if rem(counter, 4) == 0, do: incr + 2, else: incr
  {[h + incr | result], incr}
end)
|> elem(0)
|> Enum.reverse
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 31, 37, 43, 49, 57, 65, 73, 81, 91]
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! Is there also an advantage of using `:lists.reverse` over `Enum.reverse`?

Comment: Not really. `:lists.reverse` might be a teeny tiny bit faster since `Enum.reverse` will first do a type check and when it finds a list it'll delegate to `:lists.reverse`. The performance difference will be insignificant. I'll change it to `Enum.reverse`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you could also just use an equation:

```
f(n) = 1 + 2*(k+1)*(2k+j), where k = div(n/4), j = rem(n/4)
```

which in elixir would be something like this:

```
Enum.map((0..16), fn n -> 
  k = div(n,4)
  1 + 2*(k+1)*(2*k + rem(n,4))
end)
# => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 31, 37, 43, 49, 57, 65, 73, 81]
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting problem :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/46601289/24105 looks like the best solution. If you can get a formula for something, that is always the fastest. However, in this case I wanted to see if there were other solutions. Here is my take:

```
defmodule S do
  #1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 31, 37, 43, 49, 57, 65, 73, 81
  #So it's +2 for 4 first items, then +4 for next 4, then +6 for next 4. Increment is increased by 2 each four items.
  def gen1(n) do
    0..(n-2)
    |> Enum.reduce([1], fn x, [prev | _] = acc ->
      incr = ((div(x, 4) + 1) * 2)
      [prev + incr | acc]
    end)
    |> Enum.reverse
  end

  def gen2(n) do
    (n - 1)
    |> incr_series
    |> Enum.reduce([1], fn incr, [prev | _] = acc ->
      [prev + incr | acc]
    end)
    |> Enum.reverse
  end

  defp incr_series(n) do
    1..(div(n, 4) + 1)
    |> Enum.flat_map(fn x -> List.duplicate(x*2, 4) end)
    |> Enum.take(n)
  end

  def generate(n, algorithm), do: apply(__MODULE__, algorithm, [n])
end

ExUnit.start

defmodule AccumSeqTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true

  for fun <- [:gen1, :gen2] do

    describe to_string(fun) do
      test "first 4 should increment by 2" do
        assert S.generate(3, unquote(fun)) == [1, 3, 5]
        assert S.generate(5, unquote(fun)) == [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
      end

      test "second 4 should increment by 4" do
        assert S.generate(6, unquote(fun)) == [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13]
        assert S.generate(9, unquote(fun)) == [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25]
      end

      test "third 4 should increment by 4" do
        assert S.generate(10, unquote(fun)) == [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 31]
        assert S.generate(13, unquote(fun)) == [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 31, 37, 43, 49]
      end
    end

  end
end
```